# Flaws in my donut mesh

Tags: mesh, error

I'm in the [Donut tutorial, v 4, Part 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--GVNZnSROc). Andrew starts with a technical check and the warning that we'd better fix any problems in the mesh now, or they could mess things up later.

One of the problems he describes (at *t*=1:07) as "parts that have separated from your mesh." Here's an example from the video at *t*=1:15:

[image]

I have some flaws that look like that:

[image]

Andrew first describes a tedious way of fixing this, but then says we can do it easily with the Shrinkwrap Modifier. So, following his instructions, I added that, moved it to the top of the modifiers, made the donut the target, and applied it. This fixed the flaws labeled 3 and 4, but does not appear to have affected flaws #1, 2, and 5.

[image]

Since the modifier didn't work on those flaws, I tried the alternative, tedious process he had first shown. This involved selecting a vertex and, with snapping on and proportional editing off, typing "G" and then clicking without moving the cursor, so the vertex gets snapped to the same location. In previous work, he had us set "Snap With" to "Face Project", so I first tried this method without changing that setting. It did not appear to cause any change in the flaw:

[image]

I then tried the same thing with "Snap With" set to "Face". This also did not fix the problem:

[image]

I don't know if these really are flaws in the mesh that I need to fix, or if they're some kind of visual artifact that I shouldn't worry about.

So that's what I need to know: What can I do to fix these things, or should I let them be and keep going with them as is?

Comment: What he shows is vertices not sticking to the surface of the high-poly object, are you sure that it's the case for the vertices that you are highlighting? It seems to me that it's just the high-poly surface that protrudes through the surface of the low-poly, not vertices not sticking...

Comment: The only thing I'm sure of is that I don't understand what's going on here. When you say high-poly and low-poly, I suppose the icing is high-poly because it had a subdiv applied and has another subdiv added. Is that what you mean? I guess the difference in resolution allows for gaps between the surfaces. Is that what you mean by vertices "not sticking" and what he means by "parts that have separated from your mesh"? And where do you see something protruding? I don't see that.

Comment: Yes I meant the donut has probably some faces protruding through the icing faces, it doesn't mean that the vertices of the icing are not sticking to the donut faces, anyway if that was the case the Shrinkwrap will fix it so you don't have to worry